# In React Native, how can I flip a View horizontally?

Tags: react-native, transform

Suppose I have an icon like this:

```
<FontAwesome
    name={'column'}
    size={20}
    style={ /* mirror horizontally */ }
/>
```

How can I mirror this horizontally?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

React-native uses an array of transforms according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms#transform), the [`scaleX`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms#scalex) prop has been deprecated. You can scale transform on the x-axis by the inverse:

```
style={{
  transform: [
    { scaleX: -1 }
  ]
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 way that you may use to flip or reverse the view of the component through `style`

```js
fontAwesomeStyle: {
  transform: [
    {rotateX: '180deg'}, //horizontally
    {rotateY: '180deg'} //vertically
    {scaleX: -1} //horizontally
    {scaleY: -1} //vertically
  ]
}
```

but I prefer to use rotate it's because being convenient in terms of animating

Answer (score 1):

React Native transform accept array. So you have to pass value to transform as below :

```js
<FontAwesome
    name={'search'}
    size={20}
    style={{
        transform: [
            {scaleX: "-1"},
        ]
    }}
/>
```